# form submit by name not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

i want to submit nested form but i am facing two different behaviors like like if submit by index then working fine but if submit by name the parent form submiting.

```
    <form name="form1" action="/action_page.php">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <form name="form2" action="/action_page.php">
          First name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
          <br>
          Last name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form> 
    </form>
```

This is working

```
$('form')[1].submit();
```

Not working

```
$("form[name='form2']").submit(); // submit form1 instead
```

Comment: then use `$('[name="form1"]').submit();`

Comment: `form2` not `from2`

Comment: @Pedram yes correct i was type wrong. now edited.

Comment: @sal *Nested form submit is not allowed!* That's all I know!

Comment: how is possible i used **$('form')[1].submit();** its working.

Comment: @sal because it is parent not child. It's invalid `html` too. why don't use separate form?

Comment: @Pedram actually i am working in mvc razor view so dynamically creating forms for specific functionality.

Comment: @sal I still believe you can create separate `form` even dynamically, no matter `mvc` or something else, I'm not expert in `razor` But there must be a way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172809/discussion-between-sal-and-pedram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just researched myself, it seems you can't nest forms.
[Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

My solution would be to make two different forms or create them dynamically and append to the previous one.

Comment: thanks men. but question still here that why it allow to submit by index?

Comment: it's the parent form. as @pedram said.

Comment: it's a form in a form, according to your code example, which means it's nested.